# In Lord of the Rings, can quest cards with stars be used to pay for events that require you to discard other cards of a specific type?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings

In the Lord of the Rings co-op game, you can discard quest cards with stars on any activity track since they are considered wild cards; however, when an event requires you to discard cards with a specific type (travelling, hiding, friendship, or fighting), can a quest card with a star be discarded instead?

Comment: I don't see why not personally but can't find a definitive response in the rulebook. Since I don't have the board to hand can you give example text from one of the events in question?

Comment: I don't have the board in front of me at the moment, but it was one of those events where the whole fellowship has to discard 5 hiding cards (the shield icon). The other players could discard 4, and while I didn't have a single hiding card, I had a card with a star. We ultimately played the star like a shield, but a couple players were unsure about it, but the rulebook didn't help.

Comment: I found a picture of that exact example on BGG just now. In the rulebook it says: "Some cards have star symbols, which are wild. These may be played as any Activity symbol (Fighting, Friendship, Hiding, or Traveling)." but doesn't specify that it applies at all times. Would seem reasonable to do so though.

Comment: That quote makes me more inclined to believe that I should be able to do this. You are right though, it doesn't specifically say that stars can always be used as a wild card. My friend's big beef with this interpretation is that the event says that we have to discard cards that "match", and the star doesn't match the shield. An odd interpretation, but he does have a point.

Comment: Were you playing with the expansion? Just found the rules for that and that has blue shield tokens which appear different, maybe. "The symbol on the Hiding cards is a shield in the Silver Line edition" which might confuse with the expansion I guess.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't matter. There is no source to backup this guy's comment though: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/774259/discarding-cards-event

Comment: Ahaha! Also, Frodo can use any white Hobbit card for this purpose.

From the FAQ at http://freespace.virgin.net/chris.lawson/rk/lotr/faq.htm:

"Example: The Event cost at Speak Friend and Enter requires the players to discard a Friendship and Joker symbol. Frodo volunteers since he can discard any two white Hobbit cards to pay for the cost."

I believe the FAQ at this site (which is really an annotated rule set) is Knizia-approved. It's a good place to know about if you plan to play this game many times.

Comment: Good find! Definitely going to bookmark that. If you turn all of that into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Firstly I will point out there are two versions of the game: **Fantasy Flight** and the **Original***

**Original Edition**

The [FAQ](http://freespace.virgin.net/chris.lawson/rk/lotr/faq.htm) states:

> Example: The Event cost at Speak Friend and Enter requires the players to discard a Friendship and Joker symbol. Frodo volunteers since he can discard any two white Hobbit cards to pay for the cost.

Frodo's ability is the same as a wildcard (or Joker as this edition calls them) and therefore I would say it is clearly correct in this edition to use a wildcard in this manner.

**Fantasy Flight (Current)**

The [Rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/9d/88/9d880ea7-7d9b-44cb-b1b7-bed3db34e1e4/lotr-bg-rulebook-low-res.pdf) states:

> Some cards have star symbols, which are wild. These
>   may be played as any Activity symbol (Fighting,
>   Friendship, Hiding, or Traveling).

It doesn't give a specific example like the older edition but given the older edition allows the usage of wildcards for events it would seem logical that it is still allowed.